# NLP: Position feature of a word in an OCR of a document

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, ocr

I'm trying to apply NLP to an OCR document. To extract named entities, how can I use features like position of the word in the document?

For example, I have a health report I need to extract the chemical terms in the report in a particular area and avoid their occurrence elsewhere. Can I define a position feature for this in terms of `{top:x , left:y}` values?

Are there any sklearn libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You could build extraction zones to fetch this content.
In other words, group documents that have the required content within a given area in the image and then fetch the contents from that area for all images.